# How can I stop unhandled exceptions from being logged?

Tags: logging, asp.net-core-2.0

I configured a logger that I use to manually log messages.

Something from the framework (Kestrel?) now uses the configured logger to log unhandled exceptions which I dont want.

How can I avoid that?

This my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();


    services.AddTransient(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger(typeof(SentryLogger)));
    RegisterConfigs(services, Configuration);
}

   public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IHostingEnvironment env,
        IApplicationLifetime appLifetime,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        ISentryConfig sentryConfig)
    {
        ConfigureLoggers(env, appLifetime, loggerFactory, sentryConfig);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }


        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }

   private static void ConfigureLoggers(IHostingEnvironment env,
        IApplicationLifetime appLifetime, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
        ISentryConfig sentryConfig)
    {
       loggerFactory.AddSentry(sentryConfig, LogLevel.Error);
    }
```

My logger

```
  public static class LoggerFactoryExtensions
    {
        public static ILoggerFactory AddSentry(this ILoggerFactory factory, ISentryConfig config, LogLevel minLevel)
        {
            factory.AddProvider(new SentryLoggerProvider(config, minLevel));
            return factory;
        }
    }

   public class SentryLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        private readonly ISentryConfig _config;
        private readonly LogLevel _minLevel;

        public SentryLoggerProvider(ISentryConfig config, LogLevel minLevel)
        {
            _config = config;
            _minLevel = minLevel;
        }

        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            return new SentryLogger(_minLevel, _config.SentryDsn);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        { }
    }


public class SentryLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly LogLevel _minLevel;
    private readonly string _dsn;

    public SentryLogger(LogLevel minLevel, string dsn)
    {
        _minLevel = minLevel;
        _dsn = dsn;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled(logLevel)) return;

        var sentryClient = new RavenClient(_dsn);
        sentryClient.CaptureAsync(new SentryEvent(exception)
        {
            Message = state?.ToString() ?? string.Empty,
            Level = LogLevelToSentryLevel(logLevel)
        }).Wait();
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return logLevel >= _minLevel;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    private ErrorLevel LogLevelToSentryLevel(LogLevel level)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Try deriving a custom class/interface from ILogging and register that instead.  IMyLogging : ILogging,  MyLogging : ILogging.

Comment: Use log filtering (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-filtering)

Comment: @ChrisPratt that looks like a solution. I just need to know which provider logs the unhandled exceptions. Maybe system? microsoft?

Comment: It looks like the log message is generated [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L56).